# Is an infinite for loop bad practice?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I'm implementing a card game in Python, and for my class to handle players, `PlayerHandler`, I recently implemented `__next__` to simply call `next_player`. Because gameplay can be thought of in an infinite loop (The players will keep playing until they quit or win/lose), it did not make sense for it to stop iteration. However, it could seem confusing if a for loop caused an infinite loop, so should I raise a `StopIteration` somewhere?

```
class PlayerHandler():
    """Holds and handles players and order"""
    def __init__(self, players=None, order=1):
        if players is None:
            self.players = []
        else:
            self.players = list(players)
        self.current_player = None
        self.next_player()
        self.order = order

    def get_player(self, interval):
        assert type(interval) == int, "Key must be an integer!"
        if not interval and self.players:
            return self.current_player
        elif self.players:
            step = interval * self.order
            index = self.players.index(self.current_player) + step
            while index >= len(self.players):
                index -= len(self.players)
            while index <= -(len(self.players)):
                index += len(self.players)
            return self.players[index]
        else:
            raise KeyError("No players in the list!")

    def next_player(self):
        """Sets the current player to the next player to play"""
        if not self.current_player:
            if self.players:
                self.current_player = self.players[0]
            else:
                self.current_player = None
        else:
            self.current_player = self.get_player(1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.next_player()
        return self.current_player
```

Comment: I think this is a https://codereview.stackexchange.com question. That said, consider raising StopIteration after the last player, *but*, use `itertools.cycle` in the gameloop to cycle back to the first player if appropriate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an iterator that never finishes.  It's part of what iterators are for - no arbitrary limits on a sequence of values.

Comment: Technically you aren't creating an infinite loop since what you are waiting for is the players to win/lose/quit.  It is the very definition of running a while 1: loop....i.e. while there are still players....don't quit.

Comment: @Amazingred If, while reading the code, I saw a for-loop, even in the context of an infinite game loop, I would be a little confused, so I worried I was adding too much syntactical sugar

Comment: @kojiro The order will probably change as the game progresses, so itertools.cycle will probably only work if I reorder a new list based on the current order, which seems more annoying then just changing what is essentially a pointer to different players. As well, the "last player" could change in the middle of a round, which would be another (probably unnecessary) thing to keep track of

Comment: @Timidger fair enough. I still think it's a CR question, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What matters is that your code is readable. If you're worried, add a comment -- that's what they're for!

```
# Endless loop
for p in players:
    # Do game things...
```

Having said that, maybe you should StopIteration when there are no more players.